Install OS on microSD card via SSH
I didn't have sd card reader so I booted OS from USB and I am connected via SSH. Is it possible to install raspberry pi OS on sd card via SSH so I can unplug the USB?

Yes, it is possible.

I’m voting to close this question because it makes no sense to me.

If I understand this correctly it should be fairly straight-forward.  Download the latest Raspberry Pi OS image.  You should get a .img.xz file.  Decompress this with 'xz -d' and then transfer the image to the Raspberry Pi using rsync, and then on the Pi via ssh, use the dd command to install the image to the SD card, like this:
dd if=<RaspberryPiImage>.img of=/dev/mmcblk0

This will create a fresh OS on the SD card, but if you want to preserve your OS that you have already installed on the USB, then you would need to create the partitions directly on the SD card (which I'm assuming is /dev/mmcblk0 as above), create the file systems (FAT32 for /boot or /boot/firmware and EXT4 for /), then copy your USB file systems to the SD card using rsync.  After that you would need to update cmdline.txt to point to the correct file system.  Depending on what you want it might be easier to just install a new fresh image as above.  If you can provide more detail on what you want I can elaborate the instructions for moving your USB file systems to the SD card.

No this is impossible. ssh is not capable of the low level access required to create the file system.
It MAY be possible using dd or similar tools on the Pi but you are unlikely to find any existing procedure and frankly hardly worth the effort as SD Card adapters are only $5.

I think "via ssh" means not using keyboard/monitor on the pi itself, rather than ssh being the command to actually do the work - but your interpretation of the question is just as valid I guess
